# What is a buff?

Tags: hiking, clothing

What is a "buff", how is it used, and why should I have one?

I've seen them advocated in numerous places, but I'm not sure why a tube of cloth is better around my neck than a scarf, etc.

Comment: Most important use: face cover for autonomist/anarchist demonstrants like [here](http://www.taz.de/uploads/images/684x342/cN4_flora_krawallos_dpa_3sp.jpeg) ;D

Comment: I have three Buffs, I like them a lot and wear them almost daily.

The most important thing I've learned since buying the first one is getting the size right: when I use one as a headband, if it is too tight, I start having an annoying headache after a while - taking the Buff off solves the problem. I think this applies to any headwear: hats, caps, knitted stuff, headbands, helmets, headlights etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To be honest I was dubious about getting something that I thought was gimmicky, but my son’s Scout troop was selling custom Buffs to raise group funds so I ended up buying one.

A [Buff](http://www.buffwear.com/) is just a tube of lightweight, stretchy material.

I’ve found them useful in three particular situations:

- They are thin, so can be worn like a hat under a bicycle helmet for extra warmth in the winter.
- Worn round the neck it provides a comfortable scarf that helps seal any gaps around my jacket collar.
- In summer, I dip it in a stream or river and wear it round my neck to help keep cool.

I think they are versatile and useful, but certainly not a full replacement for a scarf, hat, or whatever.

Comment: Too, I use it as an eye mask at night when I'm travelling by train.

Comment: It can also be rearranged to make a skull cap (twist, then invert one half) or a simple balaclava (pull over head until top is just below eye level, then pull back overtop of your head, only your eyes are exposed).

Comment: People with long hair will put it on just to keep the wind from blowing their own hair into their face.

Answer (score 8):

I know a few people who say they're useful - and they are certainly very versatile. There's nothing very complex about them, it's just a section of stretchy material that you can wear however you like.

They can be used wet for cooling, or dry underneath a hat for a bit of extra warmth, or as a scarf.

If you're on a gentle hike or a fun backpacking trip then there's no harm in having one, they're cheap and if nothing else a bit of fun! I wouldn't say they're an essential piece of serious gear though - kit dedicated to the task it's meant to do will almost always do a better job (a proper scarf will likely be a lot warmer than a buff as a scarf for instance.)

Answer (score 6):

The primary advantage of the buff (an continuous loop of fabric) is the versatility (and fashion ability) of the item over a standard scarf or hat.

**Features** In addition to the wearable methods it can also be used as

- Eye Mask
- Facecloth
- Microtowel
- Face mask when travelling, snowboarding, desert etc
- Self-securing bandage/pressure pad

All of which can be achieved without the need of a sling, complex knot or additional tying aid.

**Benefits**

- Less likely to be lost / stolen / dropped since fabric is physically around your body
- No need for knots causing discomfort/hot spots
- One item rather than two (scarf and hat/cap)
- Lightweight
- Far thinner material than a standard scarf or hat (particularly for males)
- Multi-activity use
- Reversible

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of buffs - one is made of polartec with a piece of thin fabric attached, and another one is just the same thin fabric. I've found the first one to be very useful in winter because:

- it is very easy to put on and off; on a hike you can put it off for while you're moving and take on for a stop; this also comes very handy on climbing routes where I don't like to mess with a traditional scarf - having a thing that could be applied/removed with one hand only is nice;
- this piece of thin fabric doesn't look serious, but it helps me a lot when my chin and nose become too frozen - I just pull this part of a buff on my face and it gets warm pretty fast;
- it is not as bulky as a scarf and if I want to put one more layer of clothing, I still be able to zip a collar;

As for that small thin buff, it is just nice to have it for chilly days.

Answer (score 3):

I use Buffs a lot. If you are out on the water fishing, a buff worn like a bandit mask combined with a big hat will save you a sunburn. I wear a one as a headscarf during long hikes. It keeps the sweat out of my eyes and I soak it in organic bug repellent to keep the gnats away. For winter hikes, I again use as a bandit mask to keep my face warm and prevent windburn. The advantage is you can easily pull it up/down. To be honest, I never travel without it.